# Error when converting integer into string

Tags: python, type-conversion

```
int ("10")

Out[73]: 10

str (10)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-74-3a7e75a31039> in <module>()
----> 1 str (10)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I am currently using Enthought Canopy program. I got a traceback error when I try to use "str" to convert 10 into a string, though I can get this to work in Spyder. Why is this the case? Did I somehow manage to override the inbuilt str function?

Comment: What happens if you restart the kernel? `ctrl` + `.` and try again.

Comment: Try running "type(str)" and "help(str)"`.  Maybe you have overwritten `str`.

Comment: `del str` should restore functionality

Comment: thanks guys. These comments are really useful.